# Doesn't Show the added field using SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, django

These are my models.py

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

What I am trying to do is make a serializer which gives me list(to implement get and delete method) of all students to a particular grade using the url: 'check/{str:pk}/'.
In my serializer I am trying to combine the two models and display them together like below:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    allStudents = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ("grade", "allStudents")

    def get_allStudents(self, obj):
        s_list = []
        fields = ['name', 'grade', 'rollno']
        for stds in obj:
            s_list.append(model_to_dict(stds, fields=fields))
        return s_list
```

And my views.py for the same looks like following:

```
class IndividualGrade(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''
    PUT check/{grade}/
    GET check/{grade}/
    DELETE check/{grade}/
    '''
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
        try:
            s1 = Grade.objects.get(grade=kwargs["pk"])
            all_stds = Student.objects.filter(grade=s1) 
            a_grade = Grade.objects.get(grade=s1)
            return Response(MySerializer(a_grade, all_stds ).data)
        except Grade.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Grade with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["pk"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
        try:
            Grade.objects.get(grade=kwargs["pk"]).delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)            
        except Grade.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Grade with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["pk"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
```

This gives me the following error:

```
"message": "Grade with id: grade9 does not exist"
```

While the entry is definitely there. Because I can delete it, additionally it doesn't show me the added field.

I am really naive when it comes to serializers which aren't straight away.

Still not sure what am I doing wrong.
Also, I was wondering if I could use another serializer in SerializerMethodFiled

**EDIT**
1. To update
PUT REQUEST:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/check/grade5/`

JSON input:

```
{
    "grade": "grade5",
    "allstudents": [
        {
            "name": "Shub",
            "grade": "grade5",
            "rollno": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are coding here while understanding what is `SerializerMethodField`. You don't need to pass anything extra for getting values using `SerializerMethodField`. Means, you don't need to pass`all_stds` as parameters of `MySerializer`. So, you should update your serializer like this:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'grade', 'rollno')


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_allStudents(self, obj):
        # here obj is a Grade Object
        # we can get all the students by `obj.student_set.all()` via reverse relationship
        return StudentSerializer(obj.student_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Also, when you are using [RetriveUpdateDestroyApiView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview), it will take care of the all `get`, `patch`, `put`, `delete` method. You don't need to override them in the View. So following code suffice to fulfill your needs.

```
class IndividualGrade(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''
    PUT check/{grade}/
    GET check/{grade}/
    DELETE check/{grade}/
    '''
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    # No more code is needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the view and when I just do this bit, it shows me TypeError at /check/grade9/.'Grade' object is not iterable

Comment: Well, I made a small mistake, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I am assuming the student_set can be replaced by the related name f stated in model definition. While this works fine for delete and get, doesn't work for put.

Comment: Doesn't give me any error. It says "detail": "Not found." And doesn't accept the put.

Comment: Can you please share what is the payload and extact response from server?

Comment: I am trying to use put for two purposes here. First, to update the existing field, which it isn't doing it neither giving an error. Second, to create a new entry if {grade} is not in the database, which gives me  "detail": "Not found.". I think it is a good idea to write my own put? Also added the payload in edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188449/discussion-between-shubhankar-and-ruddra).